# How to set environment variable through vi in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, bash, java, environment-variables, vi

I'm trying to set my java environment variable but I am new to Ubuntu so don't know how to update it through Vi. I want to do the following things:

> Edit the environment file
>
> ```
> # vi /etc/environment
> ```
>
> Update the existing `PATH` variable by adding the below `bin` folders, separated with a colon`:`
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/bin
> ```
>
> `HOME` directory paths can be different based on version and update,here the version is `1.8` and the update is `151`. Add the below variables at the end of environment file, making changes for your specific version and update.
>
> ```
> J2SDKDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151"
> J2REDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/jre"
> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151"
> DERBY_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/db"
> ```
>
> The `environment` file should now be similar to this text:
>
> ```
> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/bin"
> J2SDKDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151"
> J2REDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/jre*
> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151"
> DERBY_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/db"
> ```

My problem is I don't know much about editing and saving in Vi; I tried to do it through some resources but then it start giving warning and I don't want to corrupt things so I thought I should ask for help from some experienced users, so kindly help me through guiding step by step on how to do above things in Vi through terminal. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Thank you!

Comment: you do not have to use Vi. You can use any text editor, for example run `sudo nano` if you know nano. To edit and save a file using Vi(m), see [How do I save files edited with vim?](//askubuntu.com/q/252760)

Comment: @Zanna Thank you so much for telling me ,through `sudo nano` it was quiet easy :)

Answer (score 2):

Vim steps would be:

1. From your terminal open document for editing with commands:

   - `sudo vi /etc/environment`
   - Note that the `sudo` is needed since only users with elevated priveleges can edit files in the `/etc` folder
2. To start editing the file from your keyboard use the following key combinations:

   1. Start to edit: <kbd>i</kbd>
   2. To move around, use keys <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, and <kbd>l</kbd>
3. After edit to get out of edit mode [ which was entered with <kbd>i</kbd> ], use <kbd>esc</kbd>
4. After exiting to save: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>, then [<kbd>wq</kbd> | <kbd>x</kbd>], now press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

These are just basic steps, [others](https://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html) exist so search and read up.

Quick tips:

1. Always use the <kbd>esc</kbd> to get out of vim modes.
2. I wrote something but don't want to keep it (provided you didn't do <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>), use <kbd>esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, then <kbd>q</kbd> followed by <kbd>!</kbd>, then finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Finished want to save and quit at the same time, use <kbd>esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, then <kbd>x</kbd>, now finish with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response , I have a further query after updating I was using update-alternatives to inform ubuntu about installed java paths and it gave me following response : `update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode`  
So is it all good ,I am actually doing it first time so asking thank you !

Comment: and my initial command for update-alternatives was following: 
`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/javac" 0`

Comment: Use this to see what you have: `update-alternatives --list java`

Comment: thanks ,i did that already and its showing `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java`

Actually was confused when it said "`in auto mode`" so suspected as if I'm wrong somewhere because don't know what auto mode really is ,that's why asked .

Comment: Please ask a fresh question!

Comment: Ok I was actually asking that after setting my variable I have given this command : `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java" 0`

and it responded with this `update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode`

I want to know what `0` stands for in my first given command and what  it really meant in its response when it said `in auto mode`

Hope I am clear now ,thank you!